# Windows Phone 7 location - find all available addresses around 100 meters

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

How can i find all available addresses from Bing Map service for around 100 meters of my Gps location. i have implemented functionality for getting my GPS location and Address searching.

Or if i say that i want to get the 4 nearest addresses from my GPS location within 100 meters.

Comment: What do you mean by "4 addresses" ? addresses of what ?

Comment: The nearest any 4 addresses from my gps location , i.e. from where my friend can pick me up. Any one of the address will be chosen to identify as a landmark for pickup.

Comment: uhm I dont think you can just get addresses, are you asking for House Numbers? I havent come across any way of doing that but if your looking for street names try something like here

http://www.nearby.org.uk/conversions.cgi

http://www.websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/postcode_to_coordinates_conversion_tool/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to take help from some Web Service which provides nearby locations services.